# Semi-classical spinning strings and AdS-CFT

Tags: string-theory, ads-cft, integrable-systems

I'm trying to understand how the AdS/CFT correspondence is precisely formulated when on the bulk side people are working with the string theory as a sigma model on the worldsheet expanded about some classical solution.

Such an approach is used for exaple in [Gubser, Klebanov, Polyakov (2002)](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0204051), and it is used to calculate the anomalous dimension $\Delta - S$ for some high spin $S$ operators using the idea that the dimension corresponds to the classical energy of the string state. This is further considered in [Alday, Maldacena (2007)](https://arxiv.org/abs/0708.0672) where they go beyond just the classical string energy and find a way to calculate the anomalous dimension to all orders in the t'Hooft coupling $\lambda$ by considering the low energy limit of the string theory expanded about this classical solution, which ends up being an integrable (but not conformal) sigma model.

Now I haven't read and understood everything in these papers so no doubt the answer to my question is implicit in there, but I am wondering how this correspondence of a particular *classical* string solution to an operator is connected with the correspondence in terms of the supergravity action which I see more often in introductions to AdS/CFT. Namely, the correspondence is such that if an operator $O$ appears with a source field $\phi_0$ in the CFT action, then the partition function is related to the supergravity action with the bulk $\phi$ field going to $\phi_0$ in some limit
$$Z_{boundary}[\phi_0]=e^{-S_{sugra}[\phi]}|_{\phi_0}.$$

As far as I can tell both the supergravity formulation and the classical spinning string formulation are valid in the exact same limit (large $N$ large $\lambda$), but they are different calculations. Is there a way to understand the classical string formulation of the duality in a more general way that connects it with partition functions and source fields much like is done with supergravity?